# ember-api-actions collectionAction raise error Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have model mailbox with collectionAction

```
import DS from 'ember-data'
import { collectionAction } from 'ember-api-actions'

export default DS.Model.extend({
  mailbox: DS.attr(), //display only
  pin: DS.attr(),
  download: collectionAction({ path: 'greeting'})
})
```

and when i try to call download from my component i get an error

```
import Component from '@ember/component'
import Ember from 'ember'
import FileSaverMixin from 'ember-cli-file-saver/mixins/file-saver'

export default Component.extend(FileSaverMixin, {
  hifi: Ember.inject.service(),
  notifications: Ember.inject.service('notification-messages'),
  startPlay: true,
  changeset: {},
  actions: {
    toggle () {
      let hifi = this.get('hifi')
      if (this.get('startPlay')){
        this.set('startPlay', false )
        this.get('changeset').get('download')().then((content) => {
          this.saveFileAs(this.get('filename'), content, this.get('contentType'))
          })
        this.get('play')()
      } else {
        hifi.togglePause();
      }
    },
  }
})
```

The error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined.
I check my cod/ It is the same like [ember-api-actions](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions)
But my cod did not work. Please help me. I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a trouble with using ember-changeset addon. When i put the model in my component instead of changeset model, all works fine. Thank you Paul for your efforts to help me. Question solved.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for posting the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can tell from your post, it seems `.get('download')()` is not the correct method to call the `collectionAction`. This may be all or part of your issue. You should be able to do so by using the below:

```
this.get('change').download().then(() => {});
```